# Understanding functions and undefined

Tags: javascript

Coming from a non-javascript background, I'm trying to wrap my head around 'undefined'.
I wrote a "isUndefined" function as follows:

```
function isUndefined(value) {
    return (typeof value === 'undefined');
}
```

if I type in my source this (where the variable 'boo' does not exist), I get the expected result "undefined variable".

```
if (typeof boo === 'undefined') {
    console.log('undefined variable');
}
```

if I type in the following:
    `console.log (isUndefined(undefined));`

I get the expected result 'true'

If I type in:  `console.log(isUndefined(boo));`

I get:

> Reference Error:  boo is not defined.

I expected to get 'true' - so my question is why does the first 'direct' check for undefined return the expected result, but a function() testing for it does not?

Comment: You are right to be baffled by this.

Comment: what background are you coming from?

Comment: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/understanding-undefined-and-preventing-referenceerrors/

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526131/undefined-test-not-working-in-javascript

Comment: Yeah, this is a violation of [Tennant's correspondance principle](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/08/tennents-correspondence-principle-and.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a difference between an existing variable that happens to contain the `undefined` value, and a variable that does not exist at all. If a variable name doesn't exist, then it's an error to try to reference it.

The `typeof` operator is a special case: it does accept a name even if there is no such variable of that name. But only when the name is actually used *with* the `typeof` operator.

In your function example, you use a name that does not exist, and there's no `typeof` operator *at the point where the name is used*. That's where the error occurs. It doesn't matter that you are passing the name into a function that will use `typeof`; that function never gets called because the error has already happened.

Your function would work as expected if you give it an existing variable name. Then it would tell you if that variable has the `undefined` value or not:

```
var boo;  // now boo exists but has the undefined value
console.log( isUndefined(boo) );  // will log 'true'
```

If you were checking a global variable, it would work if you said `window.boo` instead of just `boo`. That's because it is not an error to reference a nonexistent property of an object; it just gives you the `undefined` value when you do this:

```
// logs 'true' if there is no global 'boo'
console.log( isUndefined(window.boo) );
```

That wouldn't work if you wanted to check whether a *local* variable exists, though, because it won't be a property of the `window` object.

Answer (score 3):

Let me put it like this:

```
var a = 5;
function foo(v){
    v += 5;
    console.log(v);
}

foo(a);
console.log(a);   // will give you 5, not 10
```

for the same reason - when you call

```
isUndefined(boo)
```

the variable `boo` is not sent, the value of boo is sent. Since boo is not defined during the call, you get the error when you try to reach it's value.

It's worth mentioning that [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) is not a function, it's an operator

Answer (score 2):

Normally the behaviour in Javascript for trying to access a variable that does not exist is to throw a ReferenceError. The typeof operator is the exception here since its specially coded to not give such an error if you pass it a variable that does not exist.

http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3

> 11.4.3 The typeof Operator # Ⓣ
>
> The production UnaryExpression : typeof UnaryExpression is evaluated
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> Let val be the result of evaluating UnaryExpression.
>
> If Type(val) is Reference, then
>
>     If IsUnresolvableReference(val) is true, return "undefined".
>
>     Let val be GetValue(val).
> ```

To avoid the ReferenceError you can declare `boo` beforehand without assigning anything to it:

```js
var boo;
console.log(isUndefined(boo));
console.log(typeof boo == 'undefined')
```